# Adding Content (XAML) page error in Xamarin Forms shared project

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

When I add Content (XAML) to my Xamarin shared project it is showing Page1.xaml.cs in solution explorer only even though Page1.xaml was added. And I am getting error:

> The name 'InitializeContent' is not found in does not exist in the
>   current context.

I am getting this error for every new Project created.

Comment: `InitializeContent` or `InitializeComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

Restore and update all nuget packages, your Forms stuff coming with newly created project might be outdated.